# custom parameters to cups pdf printing

Tags: linux, pdf, printing, ghostscript, cups

I want to implement pdf printing from windows machine to Linux. I am using CUPS pdf in linux and driver installation in Windows.

Furthermore, I want to pass some custom parameters with printing like Full name of sender, receiver name, mobile No: to send SMS as Pdf reached etc. (I will use a custom print dialog to fetch these parameters with pint dialog.) How do I pass these along with the printing?  How I can I handle this in linux side? What is the easy method for that?

I'm not good in PostScript or Ghostscript. If thats the only solution then I will try. Any alternate solution to pass custom variables from windows to linux printer also welcome.

Comment: I think I may be able to come up with some suggestions. But I need to know: (1) Which version of a (generic?) PostScript printer driver are you using on the Windows print client? -- (2) Which version of CUPS on the Linux side of the setup?  (*I'm assuming you know how to create your custom print dialog on the Windows side! I can then tell you how you insert your custom parameters into the PostScript data stream that gets sent to CUPS, and also how you retrieve these parameters at the CUPS side....*)

Comment: thanks pipitas currently for testing I'm using "HP LaserJet 2300L PS" driver, and I achieved to print pdf file. If you any suggestion regarding custom print dialog that also very helpful to me. (2) cups 1.4.3 and latest cups generic pdf. also tested with adobe distiller too. It will be very helpful if you can advice me how to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pipitas,  I'm just starting the work, so flexible to adapt any methodology, so advice me with any solutions which helps to fullfill this requirement.

Comment: Pipitas, eagerly waiting for your advice..., please advice where to start.

Comment: Pipitas..., are u busy...?, or any more information need from my side...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get exact help for this , but I achieved this one by 2 printing. Initially printed custom parameters with reference of the next document. Then printed next document. Linux side parsed pdf using shell scripts.